# Most concise way of producing an object from another object and an array of keys to keep?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a lodash function, or possibly a combination of two, that can take an object and array of keys to keep to output the object reduced to just those keys?

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} and ['a', 'c'] => {a: 1, c: 3}
```

Comment: You can write a custom function...

Comment: I know, but there is a lot of lodash functionality and I just want to make sure I didn't miss this already being implemented, but I don't think any of the mapping/filtering functions take an array as the secondary argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://lodash.com/docs#pick

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
var keys = ['a', 'c'];

var filtered = _.pick(obj, keys);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, null, '    ') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: A lot better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. It's not lodash but it's fairly quick in assembling the object.

```
function reduce(obj, keys)
{
    var newObj = {};

    keys.forEach(function(element)
    {
        newObj[element] = obj[element];
    });

    return newObj;
}

var myObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
var reducedObj = reduce(myObj, ["a", "c"]);
```